# How to change the order of a CSV file using a script?

Tags: sorting, text-files

I have a text data with the order of **Arrival time, EDI interchange control number, EDI interchange receiver ID, EDI interchange sender ID, EDI type, Status, Sender name, Receiver name, Sender network ID, Receiver network ID, Size (in), FA status, Message error information**.

But I need the same data with different order like, **Arrival time, EDI interchange control number, EDI interchange receiver ID, EDI interchange sender ID, EDI type, FA status, Message error information, Receiver name, Receiver network ID, Sender name, Sender network ID, Size (in), Status**

For eg. data will be like,

"02/22/2016 23:59:31","00CXXXXXX1342","ZZXXXXC86YK","054784450001","997","Delivered","SAARS -IPS","MNJGH AND CO","LEAISON EXCHANGE NETWORK","CORCE VAN","234","No FA expected",""

"02/22/2016 23:59:31","000XXXX01331","ZZCCCCC186YK","086C5845401","997","Delivered","SAARS -IPS","MNJGH AND CO","LEAISON EXCHANGE NETWORK","COCE VAN","234","No FA expected",""

What is the possible solution for this? I'd like to do this in a script, so it can be automated.

Comment: What operating system are you using (Windows/Linux etc)? What scripting languages do you have access to? On Linux/Unix you could use `cut` for this, though you'd have to check that commas inside strings do not cause confusion. Otherwise pretty much all scripting languages can read CSV - PHP certainly can.

Comment: Do you want to do this in an automated fashion, or just a once-off? If the latter, just use the import feature of a spreadsheet package e.g. OpenOffice, Excel, etc. You can then move columns around as much as you like.

Comment: i needed an automated script. its going to be continous activity, and we work on windows platform.

Comment: Look into a PowerShell script then - search for "PowerShell CSV" using your usual search engine.